# Drupal site Instant Messaging

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am trying to find a module or a standalone solution that I can turn into a module that will allow me to have an instant messaging system like Facebook does on a Drupal site that I am working on. I have never setup a chat system before.

My particular requirements are rather stringent. It needs to be a solution where we host the chatting server (if one is needed separate from the website itself). It must use the site's login state (can't use an external system at all, that means no GTalk, Yahoo IM, or AIM). It also must be able to handle up to 1,000 users at any given time.

I have looked through the Drupal community and I tried the DXMPP module, but it requires Jquery UI 1.8 and that doesn't work with all of the other things that my site uses (such as Homebox). We do have a Jabber server already setup and ready to go.

Does anyone have any thoughts or options here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other modules that provides chat room are

- [DrupalChat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) does not require an additional server component/server. This ease installation but can become a performance issue as PHP/Apahce are not a good fit to efficiently server chat-like application. If scalability is an issue, it supports a more robust solution based on [Ape's Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/). The module description implies that the module allow other backend to be written.
- [Drupal Strophe](http://github.com/athoune/Drupal-Strophe) provides XMPP chat integration in Drupal. It only supports the ejabberd server.
- [Chat Room](http://drupal.org/project/chatroom) doesnt require an additional server component/server. The author is working on a [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) [integration module](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs) aimed to be used by the D7 version of Chat Room to solve the scalability issue.

Comment: Interestingly enough I actually stumbled upon DrupalChat last night after I wrote this question. I ended up going with it. Partly because of the work they mentioned doing with moving it to allow integration with an Ajax Push Engine server.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is an Instant Messenger module for D6 - http://drupal.org/project/im (although only dev version available).

Generally, the idea of basing it on node.js sounds to be the best choice. I have done something similar in the past (though it was for a Zend Framework site, not Drupal one) - done a chat very similar to Facebook's one (combined with system/new events notifications) based on node.js (http://nodejs.org/) and Socket.IO (http://socket.io/).

Have a look at following examples:

- NodeJS + WebSockets = Stoopid Easy Comet Chat: http://www.dashdashverbose.com/2010/02/nodejs-websockets-stoopid-easy-comet.html
- A simple fanout pubsub message server for node.js: https://github.com/jazzychad/fanout.node.js

Comment: There has also been done some work on creating an API for linking Node with Drupal: https://github.com/mikl/node-drupal